# How to get my files of a Windows-formatted HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, windows, filesystem

I have a very new MacBook Pro. I have an old Windows laptop that died. However I suspect the hard disk is fine. I also have an external HDD that I had used as a backup for that machine (although I hadn't been diligent in actually making backups). I wasn't using special software to make the backups, just dragging and dropping in Explorer.

The external HDD is USB2. For the laptop's internal HDD, I have [one of these](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/360953305530?lpid=82) (a Unitek hard drive dock).

How can I access the files I backed up? It's mostly MP3s and I'd like to keep them on the hard drive without buying a second hard drive to transfer them to, or reformatting. If nothing else, I at least want to *view* them so I know what I'm losing if I reformat.

Comment: Please add the backup application and the backup method (you used in Windows) to your question.

Comment: It was just drag and drop. I added it in the first paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All newer Mac OS X systems are capable of reading all common Windows file systems (FAT/FAT32/NTFS) right out of the box. So it shouldn't be a problem to access the contents of the internal HDD connected to your drive dock, given that the Unitek is working with your Mac.

Since you didn't use any special backup software (generating unaccessible file formats) the same should be valid for your external HDD.

Comment: I haven't tried plugging the Unitek into the Mac yet but I'll try it today and see what happens

Comment: HDD is dead after all but it worked fine with a USB drive, although it won't let me write anything

Comment: @ssdecontrol you have to get 3rd-party tools like `ntfs-3g` [link](http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/06/how-to-enable-writing-to-ntfs-hard.html) or `Paragon NTFS for Mac` to write to NTFS volumes.

Comment: will gparted work? I've never used any of those but that's always the one I hear talked about

Comment: Ideally id like to make a partition that will act as a boot drive, so I can do a clean Yosemite install without buying a USB stick (none of mine are large enough)

Comment: @ssdecontrol `gparted` is a disk & partition manager/editor so it doesn't help at all. Follow the above link. It's for free in contrast to `Paragon`

Comment: Oh, makes sense. Can you comment on whether my plan is feasible? Anything that would break along the way?

Comment: @ssdecontrol (reading)/writing should work flawlessly. Paragon's tool even enables NTFS partitioning but none of my NTFS formatted drives (hdd & thumb) ever were recognized properly attached to real Windows computers :-(

Comment: @ssdecontrol You may enable the hidden NTFS write functionality at your own risk, but it's not officially supported by Apple. [Details](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/). I don't know if it works properly in Yosemite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18681/discussion-between-klanomath-and-ssdecontrol).